# Teamcity does not collect Changes after one build is finished

Tags: svn, build, integration, teamcity

We use Teamcity for our build integration.
Currently we're fighting with an error.
Our Teamcity is running and also an agent runs.
When we commit something into the svn, teamcity collects all changes and then builds all of our sources.
After this process is finished, the svn isn't checked anymore. The agent remains pending all the time.

How can we achieve that the agent will listen to svn changes?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what you have configured for your build trigger settings?  I've got a TeamCity setup with a VCS Trigger configured to have a quiet period of 60 seconds.  (it'll poll SVN every 60 seconds looking for changes, and if any are found, trigger a build)

What seems strange is that your TeamCity configuration picks up the first build, but not any subsequent ones.  Do you have the proper VCS root configured as well?

Comment: Ok, here are my Build Triggering Settings: 60 seconds Quit period mode. We also have configured a VCS Root. Every VCS Checkout mode (Automatically on Server and Automatically on Agent) will produce this error. I'm not quite sure whether the Labeling rules are neede to be specified. Currently I have set them to branches=>tags and trunk=>tags. When I leave the rules empty, an Exception will occure in the teamcity.log after the build is finished. I thought that the Labeling rules are an optional setting. It's really strange that everything seems to be fine the first time a build is made.

Comment: btw.: While the one build is running and I'm tail the teamcity.log, I can see that the teamcity-server is searching for changes in svn. The log looks like the following:    INFO -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Collecting changes: root=svn: https://.../svn/atlantis/ {id=9}, fromVersion=7568_2011/04/19 17:04:52 +0200, toVersion=7568_2011/04/19 17:05:57 +0200
   INFO - jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Finish collecting changes for svn: https://.../svn/atlantis/ {id=9}; 0 changes collected 0 changes reported
After the build is finished, no more log entries occure.

Answer (score 0):

What version of TeamCity do you use? In versions 5.x, TeamCity reports changes in the log only when it found changes or when changes collecting took too long.

Also, there may be a timing issue between SVN server and TeamCity (time should be synchronized), especially if you use externals and changes occur in the externals.

Also, you may try enabling debug logging in TeamCity (server configuration -> Diagnostics). In this case, there should be more information in the teamcity-vcs.log.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation on Quiet Period, it states that it's not the interval for checking the repo. It is the time frame during which nothing is supposed to happen to your VCS root for it to kick in. To ensure that it doesn't start on the first check-in in a series of changes.

`Quiet period is a period (in seconds) that TeamCity maintains between the moment the last VCS change is detected and a build is added into the queue.`

Maybe your VCS root has a too big scope, so that check-ins occur to it very often? I'm thinking maybe all your projects share the same VCS root, so that it is rare that the whole root is "Quiet", depending on lots of other projects being committed to?

This looks vague now, but maybe you're catching the overall idea?

[Quiet mode on JetBrains site](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-QuietPeriodMode)